# Integration start idea

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to solve below integral , I tried many substitution but can't go further more . Please help me or give an idea to start for integration .
$$\int \frac{1+e^x}{1+xe^x}dx=?$$

Comment: i think there is no antiderivative known

Comment: Where did you get this integral? (Just asking because may be, that it has no elementary derivative.)

Comment: As the doctor says, [this integral cannot be expressed in any known way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjPTG.png).

Comment: $$\int \frac{-1+e^x}{1+xe^x}dx$$ would be possible, but that... no.

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative is not an elementary function.  This can be proven using the Risch algorithm.